# Getting error ORA-06502 and ORA-06512 in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have written a procedure which selects some data and inserts into a table. Code was compiled successfully. However when I pass data to execute the procedure I am getting error like the following:

```
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "CUSTOM.BPUBPF", line 51
ORA-06512: at line 7
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
       occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
       assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
       attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
       declared NUMBER(2).
 *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
       that values do not violate constraints.
```

The cursor query where it is failing is:

```
    CURSOR cur_BPubpfRecordInsert1 (templateId VARCHAR2,userId VARCHAR2,moduleId VARCHAR2, parentFileName VARCHAR2,seqNextVal VARCHAR2,contextBankId VARCHAR2,
 fileType varchar2,fileChkSum varchar2, msdStat char) IS
   SELECT MSD.MSG_SRL_NUM,
    FHD.HDR_SRL_NUM,CHECK_SUM,nvl(SUBSTR(MSG_DATA,INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctType>') + LENGTH('<PayerAcctType>'),
    INSTR(MSG_DATA, '</PayerAcctType>') - (INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctType>') + LENGTH('<PayerAcctType>'))),' ')
    AS ACCOUNT_TYPE, nvl(SUBSTR(MSG_DATA,INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctNum>') + LENGTH('<PayerAcctNum>'),
    INSTR(MSG_DATA, '</PayerAcctNum>') - (INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctNum>') + LENGTH('<PayerAcctNum>'))),' ')
    AS ENTITYID, ' ' BILLERSRVID,
    nvl(SUBSTR(MSG_DATA,INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerID>') + LENGTH('<PayerID>'),
    INSTR(MSG_DATA, '</PayerID>') - (INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerID>') + LENGTH('<PayerID>'))), ' ') AS docNum,
    MSD.STATUS, FHD.STATUS FROM TBAADM.GD_FHD FHD,
    TBAADM.GD_MSD MSD WHERE MSD.BATCH_HDR_SRL_NUM = FHD.HDR_SRL_NUM AND
    MSD.FROM_TMPL_ID = FHD.FROM_TMPL_ID AND MSD.RCRE_USER_ID = FHD.RCRE_USER_ID
    AND MSD.MODULE_ID = FHD.MODULE_ID AND IN_OUT_FILE_NAME = parentFileName
    AND MSD.RCRE_USER_ID = userId AND MSD.FROM_TMPL_ID=templateId AND MSD.MODULE_ID = moduleId
    AND FHD.FILE_TYPE = fileType AND FHD.CHECK_SUM = fileChkSum  AND MSD.STATUS = msdStat;
```

The line where it is failing is:

```
  MSD.FROM_TMPL_ID = FHD.FROM_TMPL_ID AND MSD.RCRE_USER_ID = FHD.RCRE_USER_ID
```

The select query returns the following:

```
MSG_SRL_NUM     HDR_SRL_NUM     CHECK_SUM                                   ACCOUNT_TYPE                                                                        ENTITYID                                                                            BILLERSRVID DOCNUM                                                                            STATUS    STATUS
47699           B910000007YH    1078478272                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                R         R                   
47700           B910000007YH    1078478272                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 R        R                   
47701           B910000007YH    1078478272                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              R       R                   
47702           B910000007YH    1078478272                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               R      R                   
47703           B910000007YH    1078478272                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                R         R                   
47704           B910000007YH    1078478272
```

The variable I declared to get the values from the cursor is:

```
TYPE RecTyp IS RECORD (
lv_msdSrlNum                    varchar2(12) default null,
lv_fhdSrlNum                    varchar2(12) default null,
lv_chkSum                       VARCHAR2(40) default null,
lv_acctType                     varchar2(5)  default null,
lv_acctNo                       varchar2(40) default null,
lv_billerSrvId                  varchar2(35) default null,
lv_docId                        varchar2(20) default null,
lv_msdStatus                    char(1) default null,
lv_fhdStatus                    char(1)  default null
);
```

I am not able to understand why my code is failing in that particular line.

Comment: Please post your code.It may be the case that error would have been occurring somewhere else. Not possible to guess why its not working just at looking at the info your provided.

Comment: @XING, Posting the whole code, will not be possible, since it is related to a product and hence copyrighted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer yet, but perhaps a hint. What does the following query return for you?

```
 SELECT LENGTH(msd.msg_srl_num),
  LENGTH(fhd.hdr_srl_num),
  LENGTH(check_sum),
  LENGTH(NVL(SUBSTR(MSG_DATA,INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctType>') + LENGTH(
  '<PayerAcctType>'), INSTR(MSG_DATA, '</PayerAcctType>')       - (INSTR(
  MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctType>')                                  + LENGTH(
  '<PayerAcctType>'))),' ')) AS account_type,
  LENGTH(NVL(SUBSTR(MSG_DATA,INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctNum>') + LENGTH(
  '<PayerAcctNum>'), INSTR(MSG_DATA, '</PayerAcctNum>')        - (INSTR(
  MSG_DATA, '<PayerAcctNum>')                                  + LENGTH(
  '<PayerAcctNum>'))),' ')) AS ENTITYID,
  ' ' billersrvid,
  LENGTH(NVL(SUBSTR(MSG_DATA,INSTR(MSG_DATA, '<PayerID>') + LENGTH('<PayerID>')
  , INSTR (MSG_DATA, '</PayerID>')                        - (INSTR(MSG_DATA,
  '<PayerID>')                                            + LENGTH('<PayerID>')
  )), ' ' )) AS docnum,
  LENGTH(msd.status),
  LENGTH(FHD.STATUS)
   FROM TBAADM.GD_FHD FHD,
  TBAADM.GD_MSD MSD
  WHERE MSD.BATCH_HDR_SRL_NUM = FHD.HDR_SRL_NUM
  AND MSD.FROM_TMPL_ID        = FHD.FROM_TMPL_ID
  AND MSD.RCRE_USER_ID        = FHD.RCRE_USER_ID
  AND MSD.MODULE_ID           = FHD.MODULE_ID
  AND IN_OUT_FILE_NAME        = parentFileName
  AND msd.rcre_user_id        = userid
  AND msd.from_tmpl_id        =templateid
  AND msd.module_id           = moduleid
  AND FHD.FILE_TYPE           = fileType
  AND FHD.CHECK_SUM           = fileChkSum
  AND MSD.STATUS              = msdStat;
```

Comment: Hello, I checked the lengths. They are:
5,12,10,1,1,1,1,1 respectively. So the variables for the record type should hold them successfully.